# Best practice for sending btcs with fees trough bitcoind api

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, api

i am building service which will recieve exact amount of bitcoins and then devide it for two users and send it to them. For ex.

- Recieve: 10BTC
- To user A: 5BTC
- To user B: 5BTC

Obviously i can't send through "sendfrom" exactly 5BTC because it will spend something like 5.0005.

My first solution was to hardcode .0005 fee and send amount with substracted fee. But its far away from perfect and will not reflect fee algo future changes.

So whats best practice processing this kind of transactions in this moment?

Is there way to ask bitcoind what fee will be for exact transaction or tell bitcoind to substract fee from sending amount?

Comment: Why -1? The question is pretty important. +1 from me. You could try to send raw transactions without fee or modify a bitcoind source code a bit. However, such transactions need more time to get into the block. Often you don't need to pay fee at all, so hardcoding is not the best solution. Most services cover fees from their private bitcoins.